# MYSQL database modeler showing referential integrity in diagram view

Tags: mysql, modeling, referential-integrity

Is there any database modeler for MySQL capable of showing referential integrity attributes (ON DELETE RESTRICT, ON UPDATE CASCADE ... ) in model diagram?
Can Workbench do this like ERwin modeler shown [image](https://support.ca.com/cadocs/0/CA%20ERwin%20%20Data%20Modeler%20r7%203%2011-ENU/Bookshelf_Files/HTML/ERwin%20Methods%20Guide/5787.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are after keeping track of your dependencies [Toad for MySQL](http://software.dell.com/products/toad-for-mysql/)'s Database Diagram has been quite good at it. It may miss the level of detail you look for though.

Comment: Thanks for tip, I use TOAD for Oracle management so I'm familiar with it. Maybe I should try it with MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL workbench to view your models. You can create a model by using the "Reverse Engineer" option under the "Database" menu item. You can then double click on any of your table models and go to the "Foreign Keys" tabs below, and it will show the referential integrity attributes. I currently use MySQL workbench 6.2 and it works perfectly.

Comment: My question was representation of integrity in model diagram (overview), of course one can see it in attributes.